# How to add apostrophes in a dictionnary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was just wondering if it is possible to add an apostrophe in this situation. 
I want the test key to have the value of "I don't know" not "I don". Is it possible to do so? If so how?

```
 my_dict = {
    "test": 'I don't know'
}
```

Comment: You have said it : "I don't know"

Comment: for strings in python you can either use ' or " there is no difference

Comment: "I want the test key to have the value of `"I don't know"`" - well, did you try writing ``"I don't know"``?

Comment: This has nothing to do with dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

You can either wrap the value in double quotes:

```
{"test": "I don't know"}
```

or escape the apostrophe:

```
{"test": 'I don\'t know'}
```

Comment: I'd add that you can also use triple-quoted strings, `'''I don't know'''` and `"""I don't know"""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of two things. You can to this:

```
my_dict = {
    "test": "I don't know"
}
```

or you can also do this:

```
my_dict = {
    "test": 'I don\'t know'
}
```

Either works and both are pretty much the same.